# How can i Get H Delta of the RectTransform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the H Delta in my code but failed to do so.
Please Help me.

[image: H Delta]

Answer (score 0):

Have a gander at `RectTransform.sizeDelta`. It's a `Vector2` so `sizeDelta.y` should be your H Delta.

[Unity Docs Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html)